# Generating UML diagrams using NetBeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans, uml, netbeans-7.2

I found this link:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansUML

for generating UML diagrams from existing code; admitedly using NetBeans 5.5.

I followed the outlined procedure but just get an empty -Model project.

Does the "Reverse Engineer..." method not work in NetBeans 7.2? If not then why isn't it disabled?

Thanks

Graham

Comment: Apparently not. And diverting from its "open-source" popular status, netbeans wants to sell the "UML plugin". :/

Answer (score 9):

After successfully installing [easyUML plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55435/easyuml), do the following steps in Netbeans IDE:

- File->New Project->UML->UML Diagrams Project
- Rightclick on your Java Project in the project structure window->choose "easy UML create class diagram"
- Refer to your UML project

Et voila!

Answer (score 1):

No, the NetBeans UML is only available for NB 6.7 and earlier releases. See [here](http://netbeans.org/features/uml/) for more informations.

**Alternatives:**

- [Visual Paradigm: SDE for NetBeans](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/nb/)
- [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html)

Both are listed at the NB UML website.

Answer (score 0):

There is very useful plugin for NetBeans for generating UML diagrams called ***EasyUML***.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55435/easyuml

Comment: EasyUML might be nice, but I cannot find any documentation on how to actually use it.

Comment: In NB 8.1 it throws an exception, Unable to create UML project

Comment: This plugin has many bugs (Windows10x64, NB8.1, EasyUML 1.3) and is not usefull